# How to customize the android and ios build

Tags: ipad, flutter, tablet

Is there any way to build my app only for `iPhones` and `Smartphones`?

I don't want users to be able to install my app on iPad or Tablet.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply those restrictions in the store (Google Play Store or Apple App Store).

For the Google Play store, it is located in the Supported devices | Excluded devices section.

Note that you cannot prevent the app from being installed on any device if the installation is made with the `adb install` command.

Comment: Thank you, I'm now able to exclure tablets for Android but I think IOS it's not possible.